# "Didn't need/have to do" vs "needn't have done"

Tags: modal-verbs, reported-speech, semi-modals

> If it was not necessary for someone to do something on a particular
> occasion, you say that they *didn't need/have to do it*, but in a
> reporting clause you can use *needn't do it*, as in *They knew they
> **needn't** bother about me*.
>
> If someone has done something and you want to say that it was not
> necessary, you can say that they *needn't have done it*.
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/EnglishUsage/need

1. Can *didn't need/have to do it* also be used if someone has already done it but it was not necessary?
2. In *They knew they **needn't** bother about me*, is needn't really referring to a past situation, so that we can add *...but now they do because I am currently in trouble.*

Answer (score 1):

If someone has *already* done it, but it was not necessary, you'd convey that with negated Present Perfect. Which as usual, implies a (potentially negated) past action with *current* relevance...

> *They knew they needn't **have bothered** about me*

But note that the abbreviated form ***needn't*** has been steadily losing traction over recent decades, giving way to the "do- support" forms ***don't/didn't need to***<sup>1</sup>...

[image]

I'm [actually comparing the abbreviated forms](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you%20needn%27t%2Cyou%20don%27t%20need%20to&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20need%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20do%20not%20need%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cyou%20need%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20do%20not%20need%20to%3B%2Cc0) ***you needn't*** and ***you don't need to*** above, but NGrams chooses to expand the text shown *on the chart* (it *is* doing the intended text matching).

I won't show the corpus-specific charts here, but you can do that yourself if you follow my NGram link above. And I'll just mention that this usage shift is in fact *more pronounced* with the ***British English*** corpus. Which I find surprising, since it's always been my impression that ***American English*** favours more ["function words"](https://www.thoughtco.com/function-word-grammar-1690876#:%7E:text=Function%20words%20include%20determiners%2C%20conjunctions,(those%20without%20helping%20verbs.)) and ["auxiliary verbs"](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/auxiliary_verbs.htm) than BrE. That may have been true 50-100 years ago (in the kind of texts I grew up with), but it seems to no longer be the case.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that in OP's *specific* example, my preferred phrasing would be...

> *They knew they **didn't need to bother** about me*
> ...as opposed to...
> *They knew they **didn't need to have bothered** about me*
> ...because that full-blown Present Perfect alternative is a bit too "wordy".